# Can I shorten :pyf P:\Computer Applications\Python\pi.py?

Tags: vim

To use Vim/Python like a calculator one option is executing the following command in gVim:

```
:pyf[ile] P:\Computer Applications\Python\pi.py
```

I intend on storing all my `py` files in the directory `P:\Computer Applications\Python\`. Can I add something to my `_vimrc` file so that in the future gVim knows where all my python files are stored and all I need to write is the following?

```
:pyf[ile] pi.py
```

Comment: All I can see is smiley faces in your question.

Comment: @PedroNascimento have you been drinking (something strong)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a mapping?

```
nnoremap <Leader>p :pyf P:\Computer Applications\Python\
```

You can then press <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (in normal mode) to get the `:pyf P:\Computer Applications\Python\` prefix.

**References**

- [Mapleader](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapleader)
- [:noremap](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3annoremap)
- [Normal mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal)